# Excel no longer allows assignment of certain shortcut key combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

When I switched to Office 365 from Office 2003 in 2013, three shortcut key combinations I had assigned to macros no longer worked: <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, and <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. Would anyone be able to tell me why?